# Owner of company practicing unethical behavior

Tags: ethics, sexual-harassment, florida

I am currently working for a small company in which the owner of the agency is practicing unethical behavior such as flirting with employees and has been rumored to have flirted with clients as well. This is particularly unsettling because it is a mental health agency.

There are other unethical practices that I am afraid to list for fear it will be recognized. I am looking for another job, but who do you report this behavior to when the owner of the agency is the one involved in the unethical behavior?

**Additional information provided in comments:**

- I'm in Florida.
- He says things like "I did this for you, now you should think about going out with me." It's rather vague, but uncomfortable. It doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90063/discussion-on-question-by-kathy-owner-of-company-practicing-unethical-behavior).

Answer (score 17):

> "I did this for you, now you should think about going out with me."

My God, it's like 1950.

If this happened ***to you***, obviously get a lawyer, who will (almost certainly) sue them on your behalf.

If this is happening to others (but not you), I would say you should still seek legal advice: there is a surfeit of excellent legal practices where you are; simply phone a few and get an opinion, which will cost you nothing.

> "it is a mental health agency..."

!

> "rumored to have flirted with *clients* as well"

!!!

It's a dumpster fire.

That almost reaches the level where you should call the cops.

There is a surfeit of excellent legal practices where you are; simply phone a few and get an opinion, which will cost you nothing.

Comment: it feels terrible. I appreciate your suggestion. I'm hoping I can hang in there until I either get another job or get more proof of some of the things going on. It's a very uncomfortable place to be.

Comment: Thanks for that @JoeStrazzere - you're right it's too hyperbolic a sentiment.

Comment: @Kathy - the bottom line here is simply the final sentence of this answer.  After work: just call some legal practices and seek advice, which is totally free.  You are awash in superb contingency legal practices in your region.

Comment: @Kathy The bottom line is that you're being made very uncomfortable, and clients are in actual danger.  Please do something.

Comment: @Kathy - I hope that if you land another job, you won't just leave, relieved to be out of there. This really does need to be reported. Just make sure you are clear of said "dumpster fire," when you do, if possible.

Answer (score 9):

## Find your local regulatory body to make a complaint to and GET OUT.

Do not approach affected clients, and do not try to gather evidence other than what you already have access to. Do not pass go. Just get out of there. There are too many ways this can blow up on you.

What they are doing is indeed sickening but you have to protect yourself. Pass what you legally can to the regulatory body, and start getting your CV ready.